# How to customize "value" field in a php contact form

Tags: php, forms

please tell me how i can configure my contact form field so that i can specify texts for a field. Suppose my contact form is located here: www.example.com/con.php so, if i want to give a specific title for my contact form subject field...... it should be like this:

> www.example.com/con.php?subject=this text should automatically write
>   in the field value

..
here i upload an image about this..here > https://i.stack.imgur.com/hmkwl.png
so please tell me how to do it in a php contact form script.. can i make it clear to you? Thankyou.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put this line in your form:

```
<input name="subject" type="text" value="<?php echo htmlentities($_GET['subject']); ?>"/>
```

Comment: is it possible for HTML pages? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
<input name="subject"
       value="<?php echo htmlentities($_GET['subject']); ?>"/>
```